# Relative time with moment.js but with one day granularity

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to display dates in a readable format. What I want is to display them relatively to current time (1 day ago, 2 weeks ago and so on).

In documentation, I found that I have to use [fromnow()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/), but I do not care about minutes, seconds and hours. So instead of 6 minutes ago or 2 hours ago I want to show today. Further looking into documentation has not brought me anywhere. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if it's within 22 hours, and use "today" if that's the case - otherwise use from():

```
moment() < moment('2014-05-14 13:00:00').add('hours', 22) ? 'today' : moment('2014-05-14 13:00:00').from(moment());
"a day ago"

moment() < moment('2014-05-15 13:00:00').add('hours', 22) ? 'today' : moment('2014-05-15 13:00:00').from(moment());
"today"
```